# XCode -> Build Settings names with underscores

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings

I have had a `Build Settings` tab setting's names with underscores so far. And I know it supposed to be without underscores...

I've never complained a lot about that, just reviewed once "preferences" and google a bit but stopped trying to solve it because it has never been critical.

I've updated `XCode` to newer versions but this issue remains, and I'm just interested in the reason - what is wrong for my `XCode` configuration or something else.

[image]

My interest raised when I've noticed that `XCode 5 DP2` has the same issue:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the fancy images ;)

Comment: so, where is your "+1" ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Xcode's menu, while you have the build settings open:

```
Editor->Show Setting Titles
```

Comment: @Injectios:underscore  representation is just settings name,nothing more